# How to use app.set() in Express.js so that res.json serializes Buffers using base58, not base64

Tags: node.js, json, express, serialization

I want to use base58 when calling res.json on all routes, instead of manually write encoding on every route using `const idEncoded = bs58.encode(id);`

I've currently tried this:

```
const replacerFunction = (key: any, value: any) => {
  // Check if the value is a Buffer
  if (Buffer.isBuffer(value)) {
    // Encode the Buffer using Base58
    return bs58.encode(value);
  }
  return value; // Include other properties as is
};

app.set("json replacer", replacerFunction);
```

route code -

```
app.post("/RegisterAccount", async (req, res) => {
  // Retrieve client's IP address from the custom header
  const clientIp = String(req.headers["x-client-ip"]);

  try {
    const { email, phone, nickname, features, password } = req.body;

    const response = await client.register({
      accountUri: [`mailto:${email}`, `tel:${phone}`],
      accountNickname: nickname,
      clientIp: clientIp,
      accountFeatures: [features],
      accountPassword: password,
    });

    console.log(response);

    res.json(response);
  } catch (err: any) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message || "Internal server error" });
  }
});
```

Data from  `console.log(response);` -

```
AccountRegistered {
  account: AccountDetails {
    id: <Buffer 4e 41 42 78 69 69 4a 56 42 4b 53 69 4e 53 74 6f 59 32 47 35 6a 5a>,
    uri: [ 'mailto:Lizzie.Koepp@hotmail.com', 'tel:366-643-7219' ],
    features: [ '585' ],
    nickname: 'Consultant'
  }
}
```

Output JSON from Postman -

```
{
    "account": {
        "id": "TkFCeGlpSlZCS1NpTlN0b1kyRzVqWg==",
        "uri": [
            "mailto:Lizzie.Koepp@hotmail.com",
            "tel:366-643-7219"
        ],
        "nickname": "Consultant",
        "features": [
            "585"
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see `id` is base64 instead of base58 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `id` is converted to JSON representation via [`buf.toJSON()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buftojson), so the `Buffer.isBuffer()` will return false.

You can check the value is buffer using `value?.type === 'Buffer'`, and convert the buffer JSON representation back to a buffer using `Buffer.from()`.

```js
import express from 'express';
import bs58 from 'base-58';

const app = express();
const replacerFunction = (key: any, value: any) => {
  if (value?.type === 'Buffer') {
    return bs58.encode(Buffer.from(value));
  }
  return value;
};

app.set('json replacer', replacerFunction);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const AccountRegistered = {
    account: {
      id: Buffer.from('123', 'utf8'),
      uri: ['mailto:Lizzie.Koepp@hotmail.com', 'tel:366-643-7219'],
      features: ['585'],
      nickname: 'Consultant',
    },
  };
  res.status(200).json(AccountRegistered);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Test

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:3000 | jq '.'
{
  "account": {
    "id": "HXRC",
    "uri": [
      "mailto:Lizzie.Koepp@hotmail.com",
      "tel:366-643-7219"
    ],
    "features": [
      "585"
    ],
    "nickname": "Consultant"
  }
}
```

Decode base58 `id` to verify

```
console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(base58.decode('HXRC')))
// "123"
```